React Native: Expo Auth Session with Google Firebase redirecting me to a local url : error 400
I'm using Expo with Expo Go, and trying to add Firebase Google authentication to my app.
But whenever I try logging in, I just get Error 400: invalid_request
Request details : redirect_uri=exp://192.168.1.40:8081
In my google Cloud Console, I configured :
Web client for the web client, and
Android client for the Android Client.
This is my current code i'm trying to make work :
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function Login() {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);

    const config = {
        androidClientId: 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        webClientId: 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    };

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest(config);

    useEffect(() => {
        signInWithGoogle();
    }, [response]);

    const getUserInfo = async (token) => {
        if (!token) return;
        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me", {
                headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
            });
            const user = await response.json();
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
            setUserInfo(user);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to fetch user data:", error);
        }
    };

    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            const userJSON = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
            if (userJSON) {
                setUserInfo(JSON.parse(userJSON));
            } else if (response?.type === "success") {
                getUserInfo(response.authentication.accessToken);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error retrieving user data from AsyncStorage:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
                disabled={!request}
                title="Sign in with Google"
                onPress={() => promptAsync()}
            />
            {userInfo && (
                <Text style={styles.userInfo}>
                    Logged in as: {userInfo.name}
                </Text>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    userInfo: {
        marginTop: 20,
        fontSize: 16,
    },
});


I'm guessing it doesnt work because i'm redirected to exp://192.168.1.40:8081 instead of https://auth.expo.io/@gpocil/GourmAI
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks a lot !
